# node-linkedin coonection issue

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I'm having an issue when trying to implement an exemple of connexion with node-linkedin.

I always get this error: `{ errorCode: 0, message: 'Invalid access token.', requestId: 'IN32C163DK', status: 401, timestamp: 1459554255669 }`

Here my code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')('app-id', 'secret', 'callback');

router.get('/linkedin', function(req, res) {
console.log("hello linkedin");
var linkedin = Linkedin.init('my_access_token');
linkedin.companies_search.name('facebook', 1, function(err, company) {
console.log(company);
name = company.companies.values[0].name;
desc = company.companies.values[0].description;
industry = company.companies.values[0].industries.values[0].name;
city = company.companies.values[0].locations.values[0].address.city;
websiteUrl = company.companies.values[0].websiteUrl;
});
});
```

Here the link of package: https://github.com/ArkeologeN/node-linkedin

Can you help me on that please?

Thanks

Comment: are you correctly passing the access toke that you have received from linked in? have you followed the process given here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that.

```
router.get('/linkedin', function(req, res) {

Linkedin.auth.getAccessToken(res, req.query.code, req.query.state, function(err, results) {
    if ( err )
        return console.error(err);

    var linkedin = Linkedin.init(results.access_token || results.accessToken);
```

});

```
linkedin.companies_search.name('facebook', 1, function(err, company) {
console.log(company);
name = company.companies.values[0].name;
console.log(name);
});

});
```

});